# $\sqrt {2} - \sqrt {6} + 3$ is equal to the ratio of two linear functions of $\sqrt {2} + \sqrt {3}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

can you help me show that

$\sqrt {2} - \sqrt {6} + 3$ is equal to the ratio of two linear functions of $\sqrt {2} + \sqrt {3}$.

So I know that both $\sqrt {2}$ and $\sqrt {3}$ can be expressed as cubic functions of $\sqrt {2} + \sqrt {3}$, also I see that $\sqrt {2} - \sqrt {6} + 3 = \sqrt {2} - \sqrt {2}\cdot\sqrt {3} + (\sqrt {3})^2$ but I am not sure how to pull it all together.

Thanks,

Edit 1: changed words “function in” to “function of”

Edit 2: to clarify, for example $\sqrt {2}$ can be expressed as $((\sqrt {2} + \sqrt {3})^3 - 9 (\sqrt {2} + \sqrt {3}))/2$ this is what I mean by “a function of $\sqrt {2} + \sqrt {3}$”

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "linear function" in $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$? Do you mean $a\sqrt 2 + b \sqrt 3$ for rational (or integral) $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand any of the sentences in this question. I feel like should be able to, though, as this question has the "precalculus" tag.

Comment: @AdamRubinson - Yeah, it's not clear.

Comment: Also, is there supposed  to be that square root on the $3$ in your last equation? 'Cause there isn't one in your title.

Comment: Sorry about lack of clarity, added two edits. I hope you can see what I mean now. Regarding the root on 3, the title is correct, fixed equation in the body of the post

Comment: To my comprehension, the question is telling you to solve
$$\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{6}+3=\frac{a(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})+b}{c(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})+d}$$

Comment: So you meant *rational* linear function, like $f(x)=ax+b$, where a and b are rational? If so, please update this question to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve
$$\sqrt2-\sqrt6+3=\frac{a(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)+b}{c(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)+d}$$
with rational $a,b,c,d$, multiply with the denominator and rearrange to
$$(\cdots)\sqrt6+(\cdots)\sqrt2+(\cdots)\sqrt3+(\cdots)=0.$$
The expressions you obtain for the parentheses must all be zero (why?).Use these to find $a,b,c,d$ - noting that this is possible only up to a common factor, of course.